# canvasで描いた絵をlocalstorageに保存してデータを表示したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

canvasとlocalstorageを使ったwebアプリケーションを作っているのですが、

canvas内に描いたデータをlocalstorageに出力して、そのデータを画像で表示するところまで行いたいと思っています。

色々調べてみるとbase64を使って、描いた絵を文字列として認識するのは分かり、
localstorageには、png型で記載されているのですが、いまいちそのデータを画像表示する書き方が分かりません。

```js
$("#save").on("click", function(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById("drawarea");
 var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
 localStorage.setItem(save, base64);
});


$(window).on("load", function(){
 if(localStorage.getItem("save")){
  var base64 = localStorage.getItem("save")
  $("#drawarea").val(base64);
 }
});
```

canvasつまり"drawarea"にbase64にセーブしたデータを表示したいのですが、
これだとリロードしても表示されないままです。

どう記述するのが良いのか教えて欲しいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)で得られる文字列データは、base64というより[Data URI scheme](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)で表現されたURLです。
これはそのままURLとして扱えますから、単に`HTMLImageElement`オブジェクトの`src`プロパティに設定すれば読み込むことができます。

```
// Data URLの書き出し
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 200;
var g = canvas.getContext("2d");
g.fillStyle = "mediumblue";
g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 200);
g.fillStyle = "crimson";
g.fillRect(200, 0, 100, 200);
var url = canvas.toDataURL();　
localStorage.setItem("save", url);

// Data URLの読み込み
var img = new Image();
img.src = localStorage.getItem("save");
img.onload = function () {
    var drawarea = document.getElementById("drawarea");
    var g = drawarea.getContext("2d");
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tc39v7ss/3/

Comment: なるほどです。
上記のようにsrcプロパティで同様に書いたところ
canvas_base.htmlがnullで返ってきてしまい、imgが表示されずエラーになってしまっています。
どのような原因が考えられるでしょうか？

Comment: 失礼しました。
canvas_base.htmlにsaveされてはいるのですが、リロードした際に出ておりません。
いただいたurlのjsfiddleの方を見てみるとsaveされているimgが、
Dimensions 500×500なのですが、私の方では300×150となっています。
150のため上が切れていて見れないのかと思うのですが、どう問題になりますでしょうか？

Comment: ちなみにhtmlでは、
<canvas id="drawarea" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
と設定しています。

Comment: ちょっとコメントが全体的に何を言っているのかわかりません。整理すると
(1)何らかのエラーが起きている 
(2)リロードしても期待したように表示されない
(3)保存したいCanvasのサイズは500x500なのに、実際に保存された画像のサイズは300x150で、このサイズの違いが表示されない原因かもしれない
、ということでしょうか？
これ以上コメントで不具合を明されても通じそうにありませんし、「百聞は一見にしかず」ですから、
スタックオーバーフロー上のコードスニペットなりjsFiddleなりで、
そのプログラム全体を示してもらうしかないでしょう。
canvasのタグの記述だけ抜粋して示されても、あまり回答の役には立ちません。